# Как поместить кнопку внутрь input?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать такой input?

```
        <div id="file-info" style="display: none;">
            <input id="file-name" type="text" readonly/>
            <button class="button-drop-file"></button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Внутрь - никак. Сделать визуально как будто внутри - можно.

Answer (score 0):

Один из **сотни** способов:

```css
#file-info {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.button-drop-file {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1px;
  top: 1px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="file-info">
  <input id="file-name" type="text" readonly/>
  <button class="button-drop-file">x</button>
</div>
```

Спозиционировать кнопку абсолютно.

Answer (score 0):

> Как сделать такой input?

Например так...

```css
.test {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.test input {
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
}
.test button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="file-info" class='test'>
  <input id="file-name" type="text" value='Название презентации' />
  <button>X</button>
</div>
```